# Add multiple image in textview

Tags: android, image, textview, icons

[image]

I want to make something like image above, but I failed to achieve!

**add_expenses**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Receipt"
        android:drawableTint="@color/blue"
        android:drawablePadding="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/receipt"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_textview" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**roundedcorner_textview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/light_purple"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>

</shape>
```

**My Output**

[image]

1. How to bigger the image?
2. I want the color of arrow is black, not blue.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: use drawable black images with padding in it.And remove the paddingTop attribute

Comment: Please check the image dimension. the corners of image should be equally spaced. and also please try textview Gavity center vertical also. may be that can solve your problem. and remove padding top in text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
----------------- add_expenses.xml -------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_textview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="38sp"
            android:text="Receipt"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/recepit"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/forward_arrow"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

---------------- rounded_corner_textview.xml ------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>

</shape>

------------------ forward_arrow.xml --------------------------

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/forward_arrow"
    android:tint="@android:color/black"
    />

------------------recepit.xml--------------------------

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/recepit"
    android:tint="@color/blue"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_textview"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_receipt_white" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/li_about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:text="Receipt"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:src="@drawable/forwardbutton"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!--  You Can This View Achieve like this -->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_textview"
          >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NoData"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/receipt"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
            android:drawableTint="@color/blue"
            android:text="Receipt"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            />
      </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TextView. Use imageview.

First keep the background of relativeLayout to a rounded corner textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_textview">

    <ImageView

        <!--  Set its src to the blue page image  -->
    />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_textview"

        <!--  Keep this to the right of the above image view  -->
    />

    <ImageView

        <!--  Set its src to the right arrow
              and layoutalignParentright="true".
        -->
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Rough figure of layout.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below things in drawable XML for reducing or increasing the size of the image:

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
```

For changing color, change the color in the XML file.

Answer (score -1):

**1. How do I make the image bigger?**

Answer: if you want increase the image size then increase the height of the textview or use the `gravity` property to center both your images in it.

**2. I want the color of arrow is black, not blue.**

Answer: If you want a black arrow instead of blue then replace that blue drawble image with black arrow drawble image.